# How to run Auto-Weka by command Line in linux

Tags: linux, terminal, weka

I have a large data set of ~140000 rows and ~20 features on which i want to run Auto Weka but using GUI i am only able to run it for few hours as i have to keep my laptop on. So i want to run it on server by command line. But i am unable to figure out how to do it.

I am using this command

```
java -cp autoweka.jar weka.classifiers.meta.AutoWEKAClassifier -t train.csv -timeLimit 15 -no-cv
```

But getting this : **Error: Could not find or load main class weka.classifiers.meta.AutoWEKAClassifier**

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the folder of autoweka to your server and add it to your classpath.
It will be something like

```
-classpath "homedtic/weka-3-7-13/autoweka.jar:/homedtic/weka-3-7-13/lib/*"
```

in this case the contents of the folder are in the lib directory.